# Dockerfile COPY file to two locations

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to copy a file to two or more different locations within the container:

```
COPY .ssl/cert.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/test/cert.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/live/cert.pem
```

the `.ssl/cert.pem` is the file to copy, the other two paths are the destinations. The above doesn't work.

Is there a way to achieve this without unnecessarily duplicating the `COPY` statement n times?

Comment: Did you try COPY twice?

`COPY .ssl/cert.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/test/cert.pem`

then

`COPY .ssl/cert.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/live/cert.pem`

Comment: @LionelMontrieux that'd work yes, but it seems like unnecessary duplication?

Comment: It's *necessary* duplication, it makes it clear that you're coping the same file to multiple locations. You can only specify multiple sources, not multiple destinations, with [the COPY instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I see your point, but there are shorthands everywhere, so I was wondering if there is a shorthand for this. Imagine copying this to 10 locations.

Comment: (You'd also need two `cp` calls outside of Docker land.)

Comment: @DavidMaze With `cp` alone yes, but not in conjunction with piping :)

Comment: Why would you need the certificate in ten different places inside the same container (for that matter, why do you need it in two)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe because letsencrypt places every domain in a seperate folder, and when you have multiple domains it will be in multiple folders. But frankly, this doesn't really relate to the question.